# Simulater/Generated switch statement range in c

Tags: objective-c, c, macros, switch-statement, c99

Is there a hack to support range case in a c(99?) or objective C switch statement ?
I know this is not supported to write something like this:

```
switch(x)
   case 1:
   case 2..10:
   case 11:
```

But I was thinking there should be a way to generate code with a #define macro. Of course
I can define a macro with the list of cases but I was hoping for a more elegant way like
CASERANGE(x,x+10) which would generate:

```
case x
case x+1
case x+2
```

is it even possible ?

Comment: Why are there two `case 1` there? Is the second one `case 11`?

Comment: Why not simply use `if`-statements instead?

Comment: the second 1 is a typo. If statements do not solve the problem. I still have to write them all. And anyway I think switch statement are clearer to read depending of the situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GCC has an [extension to the C language](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Case-Ranges.html#Case-Ranges) that allows something similar to your first example, but other than that, if there was a portable/ANSI way of doing it, it would have been done by now. I don't believe there is one.

Comment: +1 This also appears to be supported by Clang/LLVM, so *should* be safe to use going forward.

Comment: Nice ! I had no idea those extensions existed. I'm going to use them. I'm back to C after having played with Ruby and I got used to high level programming tricks.

Comment: contrary to your belief, there is a way to do this in C99 and which doesn't even need the gcc extensions. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Doing this with macros is near to or impossible. Compiler extensions exist, but they are compiler specific and not cross-platform/standard. There is no standard way to do this, use if/else chains instead.

Answer (score 2):

In modern C (C99, with variable length macros), doing this with macros is possible. But you probably wouldn't want to code this completely yourself. [P99](http://p99.gforge.inria.fr/) provides a toolbox for this. In particular there is a meta-macro `P99_FOR` that allows you to do unrolling of finite length argument lists.

```
#define P00_CASE_FL(NAME, X, I) case I: NAME(X); break
#define CASES_FL(NAME, ...) P99_FOR(NAME, P99_NARG(__VA_ARGS__), P00_SEQ, P00_CASE_FL, __VA_ARGS__)
```

would expand `CASES_FL(myFunc, oi, ui, ei)` to something like

```
case 0: myFunc(oi); break; case 1: myFunc(ui); break; case 2: myFunc(ei); break
```

**Edit:** to reply to the concrete question

```
#define P00_CASESEP(NAME, I, X, Y) X:; Y
#define P00_CASERANGE(NAME, X, I) case ((NAME)+I)
#define P99_CASERANGE(START, LEN) P99_FOR(START, LEN, P00_CASESEP, P00_CASERANGE, P99_REP(LEN,))
```

where `P00_CASESEP` just ensures that there are the `:;` between the cases, and `P99_REP` generates a list with `LEN` empty arguments.

You'd use that e.g as

```
switch(i) {
P99_CASERANGE('0',10): return i;
}
```

Observe the `:` after the macro to keep it as close as possible to the usual case syntax, and also that the `LEN` parameter has to expand to a plain decimal number, not an expression or so.

Comment: Would you expand on that?  Specifically, how would the OP’s code look with P99?

Comment: @jcsalomon: right, see my edit. I think that I'll add that to P99, too.