# How to use ellipsis in c's case statement?

Tags: c, switch-statement

```
CASE expr_no_commas ELLIPSIS expr_no_commas ':'
```

I saw such a rule in c's syntax rule,but when I try to reproduce it:

```
int test(float i)
{
switch(i)
{
  case 1.3:
    printf("hi");
}
}
```

It fails...

Comment: Why do you think that ellipsis is a single period? It's the … symbol, i.e. three period would be my first guess.

Comment: switching on a `float` when binary representation is inaccurate is dangerous.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Simulater/Generated switch statement range in c](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4680502/simulater-generated-switch-statement-range-in-c)

Comment: @Benoit: Is it really dangerous, or just flawed?

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal: you're right, it is flawed.

Comment: "I saw such a rule in c's syntax rule" -- saw it where? -1 on this question (I wish I could dock it more).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

OK, this involves a bit of guesswork on my part, but it would appear that you're talking about a `gcc` extension to C that allows one to specify ranges in `switch` cases.

The following compiles for me:

```
int test(int i)
{
  switch(i)
  {
  case 1 ... 3:
    printf("hi");
  }
}
```

Note the `...` and also note that you can't switch on a `float`.

Answer (score 11):

This is not standard C, see 6.8.4.2:

> The expression of each case label
>   shall be an integer constant
>   expression

Answer (score 10):

[ELLIPSIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis) means `...`, not `.`. The statement should be like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int x;
    scanf("%d", &x);

    switch (x) {
       case 1 ... 100:
           printf("1 <= %d <= 100\n", x);
           break;
       case 101 ... 200:
           printf("101 <= %d <= 200\n", x);
           break;
       default:
            break;
    }

    return 0;    
}
```

BTW, this is a [non-standard extension of `gcc`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Case-Ranges.html#Case-Ranges). In standard C99 I cannot find this syntax.

Comment: @assem This is pretty non-portable. Don't do it, use if/else.

Comment: @JimBalter There is also the thing that you may not need portability between compilers. When you don't, this may be useful.

Comment: @PaulStelian No, it's not useful. (Nor is posting such comments more than 8 years later.)

Comment: @JimBalter It definitely is in low-level code such as the one I'm working on. About the necroposting I have to agree though.