# Are Elipses in case statements standard C/C++

Tags: c++, c

I was browsing some code in the linux kernel and I came across the statements like `case '0' ... '9':`

To try this out I created the test program below.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    const int k = 15;

    switch (k)
    {
    case 0 ... 10:
        std::cout << "k is less than 10" << std::endl;
        break;
    case 11 ... 100:
        std::cout << "k is between 11 and 100" << std::endl;
        break;
    default:    
        std::cout << "k greater than 100" << std::endl;
        break;
    }
}
```

The program above does compile although I have never come across the elipses in case statement construct before. Is this standard C and C++ or is this a GNU specific extension to the language?

Comment: Ah, the swan song of Visual Basic.

Comment: [what does this syntax of switch case mean in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17699746/995714)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are triple dots inside a case (case '0' ... '9':) valid C language switch syntax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7043788/are-triple-dots-inside-a-case-case-0-9-valid-c-language-switch-syntax)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

That is the [case range](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Case-Ranges.html) extension of the GNU C compiler, it is not standard C or C++.

Answer (score 7):

That's an extension.  Compiling your program with `-pedantic` gives:

```
example.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
example.cpp:9: error: range expressions in switch statements are non-standard
example.cpp:12: error: range expressions in switch statements are non-standard
```

`clang` gives even better warnings:

```
example.cpp:9:12: warning: use of GNU case range extension [-Wgnu]
    case 0 ... 10:
           ^
example.cpp:12:13: warning: use of GNU case range extension [-Wgnu]
    case 11 ... 100:
            ^
```

Comment: Now, I wonder why that would be pedantic. I assume -Wall show the same?

Comment: @sehe, `-Wall` does not show those warnings/errors for me, using either clang or gcc.

Comment: thx. That is kind of amazing, seeing how much emphasis is on standards compliance. I for one have never dreamed to even try using '...' in my switch statement :)

Answer (score 1):

This is a GCC extension to C, mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5327896/how-to-use-ellipsis-in-cs-case-statement/5327995#5327995) to what is basically a duplicate question, and confirmed [in the GCC documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.2/gcc/Case-Ranges.html).