# Are triple dots inside a case (case '0' ... '9':) valid C language switch syntax?

Tags: c, switch-statement

I noticed this in open source code files for [DRBD](http://www.drbd.org/) software ([user/drbdtool_common.c](http://linuxha-net.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/drbd-8.3.9/user/drbdtool_common.c))

```
const char* shell_escape(const char* s)
{
    /* ugly static buffer. so what. */
    static char buffer[1024];
    char *c = buffer;

    if (s == NULL)
        return s;

    while (*s) {
        if (buffer + sizeof(buffer) < c+2)
            break;

        switch(*s) {
        /* set of 'clean' characters */
        case '%': case '+': case '-': case '.': case '/':
        case '0' ... '9':
        case ':': case '=': case '@':
        case 'A' ... 'Z':
        case '_':
        case 'a' ... 'z':
            break;
        /* escape everything else */
        default:
            *c++ = '\\';
        }
        *c++ = *s++;
    }
    *c = '\0';
    return buffer;
}
```

I have never seen this "triple dot" construction (`case '0' ... '9':`) in C before.  Is it a valid standard C language? Or is that some kind of preprocessor magic? What's going on here?

Comment: for the interested it is standard in the [D programming language](http://www.d-programming-language.org/statement.html#SwitchStatement)

Comment: It is supported on clang also FWIW.

Comment: [what does this syntax of switch case mean in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17699746/995714), [Are Elipses in case statements standard C/C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5924681/995714)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As others have said, this is a compiler-specific extension.  Invoke the compiler with the right options (say, `gcc -std=c99 -pedantic`), and it should warn you about it.

I'll also point out that its use is potentially dangerous, apart from the fact that another compiler might not implement it.  `'a' ... 'z'` denotes the 26 lowercase letters -- but the C Standard doesn't guarantee that their values are contiguous.  In `EBCDIC`, for example, there are punctuation characters among the letters.

On the other hand, I doubt that either gcc or Sun C supports systems that use a character set in which the letters *aren't* contiguous.  (They are in ASCII and all its derivatives, including Latin-1, Windows-1252, and Unicode.)

On the other other hand, it excludes accented letters.  (Depending on how `DRBD` is used, that may or may not be an issue.)

Comment: If there is one port of gcc supporting EBCDIC, it is s390x-ibm-tpf

Answer (score 12):

That's a non-standard language extension.

Probably GCC: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.2/gcc/Case-Ranges.html.

Comment: will it be included in the next standard?

Comment: @osgx: Nope, at least not as of the latest draft of [C1X](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C1X).

Comment: @osgx: Not in C11, not in C17, and not proposed for C2X.

Answer (score 3):

No, this is an [extension of GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.2/gcc/Case-Ranges.html#Case-Ranges).

Answer (score 3):

This is not standard C, but is an extension found in the Sun C compiler.

Refer to:  [2.7 Case Ranges in Switch Statements](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19205-01/820-7598/giphi/index.html) at Oracle's web site.

UPDATE: Apparently, not just Oracle!  :-)