# What does this syntax of switch case mean?

Tags: c, switch-statement

I saw some C code like this:

```
int check = 10:

switch(check) {
            case 1...9: printf("It is 2 to 9");break;
            case 10: printf("It is 10");break;
}
```

What does this `case 1...9:` mean? Is it standard?

Comment: thank you man, I basically can guess what does this mean, but I need to get confirmed and know whether this is standarded?

Comment: @user2131316 As I noted below you can use `gcc -std=c99 -pedantic` to check against a specific standard

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is "..." in switch-case in C code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18853502/what-is-in-switch-case-in-c-code)

Comment: [Are Elipses in case statements standard C/C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5924681/995714)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a GNU C extension called *case range*.

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Case-Ranges.html

As noted in the document, you have to put spaces between the low and high value of the range.

```
case 1 ... 9:
    statement;
```

is equivalent to:

```
case 1:
case 2:
case 3:
case 4:
case 5:
case 6:
case 7:
case 8:
case 9:
    statement;
```

Comment: ok, thank you, but this GNU C is standard C or is it supported by C99 or what?

Comment: As far as I can tell `1...9` is a syntax error, there needs to be a space.

Comment: @user2131316 GNU C is not C. It is an extension to C.

Comment: then can we use it as normal or we need to install something in order to build it?

Comment: @user2131316 by default `gcc` is c89 + GNU extensions.

Answer (score 1):

This is [`gcc extension`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Standards.html), they easiest way to usually figure this out with `gcc` at least is to use `-pedantic` argument:

```
gcc -pedantic
```

will warn:

```
warning: range expressions in switch statements are non-standard [-pedantic]
```

and if you wanted to check against a specific standard, for example `c99`, you do as follows:

```
 gcc -std=c99 -pedantic
```

Also, this is not correct:

```
case 1...9:
```

you need spaces between the dots and numbers:

```
case 1 ... 9:
```

as noted in the [document](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Case-Ranges.html#Case-Ranges):

> Be careful: Write spaces around the ..., for otherwise it may be parsed wrong when you use it with integer values.