# Switch statements with case ranges, is it possible?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, switch-statement

So I am working on a switch statement but I am not quite sure if I am doing this right. This is my first tiny program using C++ (visual studio 2010) and I am not sure that I am using the switch statement quite right. What I am trying to do is have a person input numbers. I have a counter set up to count the number of inputs as well as I have a running total to output at the sum of all numbers inputted.

```
while (additional_input > 0) 
{
    cout << "Enter additional number, use 0 to exit: ";
    cin >> additional_input ;
    count ++; //increment the counter
    //Do the addition
    sum += additional_input; //sum up all inputs

} //end of the while statement 

switch (sum){ //this is where I get into trouble
case 0-99: cout << "\n\n"; //original question, can I do this?
    cout << "Thank you. The sum of your numbers is........: " << sum << endl ;
    cout << "The total number of inputs read..............: " << count << endl;
    cout << "The sum of your numbers is less than 100" << endl;
    return 0;
    break;
case 100: cout << "\n\n"; //and so on
```

So my question is whether or not this is possible. Can I use this for a case?

Comment: No, it's not possible. `0-99` means _subtract 99 from 0_.

Comment: So is there no way to use a range as a case?

Comment: gcc allows this as an extension but it is not standard and is non-portable, see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18853502/what-is-in-switch-case-in-c-code/18853544#18853544) and I think clang does too. Otherwise using if statements is an alternative.

Comment: In this case you're better off going with an if statement like `if (sum >= 0 && sum <= 99)`. Of course the if statement would be instead of a switch statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Standard C++ does not allow case ranges, in your code `0-99` will just end up being evaluated as `0` minus `99` which means what you have is essentially:

```
case -99:
```

one alternative is to use an *if statement* instead so:

```
case 0-99
```

would become:

```
if( sum >= 0 && sum <= 99 )
{

}
```

Some compilers including `gcc` offer [case ranges](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Case-Ranges.html#Case-Ranges) as an extension but this would make your code non-standard and not portable and since you are using Visual Studio probably does not apply.

Answer (score -1):

I actually figured this out. It is better to set a case based on the sum. Since I had 3 cases that I was working with, I just made it select the case based on the the total that I had previously gotten. Below is my code:

```
while (additional_input > 0) 
{   
    cout << "Enter additional number, use 0 to exit: ";
    cin >> additional_input ;
    count ++; //increment counter
    //Do the addition
    sum += additional_input; //sum up all inputs

} //end of the while statement 
if (sum < 100){ //set condition for option 1
    option =1;}
else if (sum == 100){//set condition for option 2
    option =2;}
else if (sum > 100)
{option = 3; //last resort option 3
}

switch (option)
{ 
case 1: cout << "\n\n";//new line
    cout << "Thank you. The sum of your numbers is........: " << sum << endl ;
    cout << "The total number of inputs read..............: " << count << endl;
    cout << "The sum of your numbers is less than 100" << endl;
    break;
case 2: cout << "\n\n";//new line
```

Works like a charm.

Comment: Why use the switch statement at all?  Just move the cout statements into the if/else statements and call it done.

Comment: This was for an assignment for school. Case statements were required. I don't know why everyone was downvoting this....

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I assume it was downvoted because even though this solution solves your homework assignment, it doesn't answer the question "Are case ranges possible?"

Comment: Also @Shafik gave a solution that directly answered your question, and you should give him credit by marking his solution as the best answer.