# Default in switch case

Tags: c++, c, if-statement, switch-statement

The below is the code which I need to optimize and planned that it would be good to move to the *switch* construct. But I can compare in *case*. So I planned to make the comparison (len > 3) as the *default* case.

If I make the comparison part (len > 3) as the default case and add the *default* as the first in the switch, will it be faster?

Or how can I make the below code as a switch statement?

```
if ( len > 3 ) {
    // Which will happen more often;
}
else if ( len == 3 ) {
    // Next case which may occur often;

} else if ( len == 2 ) {
    // The next priority case;

} else {
    // And this case occurs rarely;

}
```

Comment: You can't move a range from 4 to the max value into a switch. It needs compile-time case labels.

Comment: @chris Thanks for your reply. But I remember I studied somewhere even if you have more the two else if its better to move to switch?

Comment: Well, sure it can look better if it's actually a possible move. This one isn't.

Comment: @2vision2 it can be more readable and scalable but that's not related to performance

Comment: Thanks for all your answers and I would accept @icepack answer as its the best one.

Comment: @chris if the performance of this really was critical (which I kind of doubt), turning the inequality into a direct (switchable) comparison, is quite possible.

Comment: @JasonD, I suppose you could put both the `> 3` and `else` into the `default` case. It's really not worth doing to try to include `> 3` as part of the cases, though.

Comment: @chris actually I wasn't quite thinking of that - I've added an answer to show what I mean, though I agree that it's almost certainly not the right approach in this case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Probably not. Both `if...else` and `switch...case` are high-level constructs. What slows you down is the branch prediction. The better your prediction is the faster your code will run. You should put your most occurring case in first `if`, second  in the `else if` and so on, just like you wrote. For `switch` the result depends on the internal compiler implementation which can reorder the cases despite your own order. The `default` should be actually reserved for the less occurring situations because rest of the conditions must be checked before falling back to `default`.

To conclude all this, performance-wise usage of `if...else` is optimal as long as you set your conditions in the correct order. Regarding `switch...case` it's compiler specific and depends on the applied optimizations.

Also note that `switch...case` is more limited than `if...else` since it supports only simple comparison of values.

Comment: thanks for your reply. there is a case where switch will select the correct case at first instance. I read this somewhere. But am not sure. Some kindda sortin used in swith I guess. correct me if am wrong.

Comment: The running code exams the first `case`, after that the second and so on. So you can "sort" the cases by the order of occurrence, from high to low

Comment: No am talking about how switch internally works.Its sure that it is much faster than else if ladder. and also it is faster because it will select the case by using sorting techniques internally?

Comment: C Standard doesn't specify how the `switch` should be implemented. Though it's almost certainly parsed into a construct similar to a long `if..else`

Comment: Anyhow thnaks... I just wanna know how switch internally implemented or works. I read some where I couldnt find the source where i read. Sorry to trouble you more.\

Comment: AFAIK, some compilers actually "implement" a `switch` with enough cases as a binary search, so it can be better than a purely linear `if ... else` combo.

Comment: @Angew Interesting remark. It should be very possible since an argument to the `switch` is an integer. But this raises another question - is it really an optimization? Binary search will result in `O(logn)` search time for every option but this completely ignores branch prediction thus arranging cases by order of occurrence might yield better results. Interesting topic, though

Comment: @icepack I was told by a friend who did some research into optimisation as part of his Master's thesis. Apparenty, *at that time,* there was research showing that it paid off. But I have no idea how valid it is now.

Comment: @Angew it's probably very specific to a use-case.

Comment: @Angew this is what I read "binary search". Interesting. Could you please add some links if possible?

Comment: @Angew to add some more to ypur points its better to give case in some sorted way to make switch work faster??

Comment: @Angew I am planning to make this as another question. What say?

Comment: @2vision2 Go for it. There are probably some insights people can provide. You can also try on http://cs.stackexchange.com

Comment: @icepack http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14067547/how-switch-case-statement-implemented-or-works-internally/14067829#14067829 Posted here and found some interesting links too... jus have a look. Thanks.

Comment: @Angew started a discussion here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14067547/how-switch-case-statement-implemented-or-works-internally/14067829#14067829

Comment: This answer is simply wrong.  Generally speaking, the order you put the cases in a switch is irrelevant; the first thing the compiler does is sort the cases, and process them in sorted order.  (But it depends on the compiler.  Most modern compilers have options which allow them to use profiler output to reorganize the code.  In such cases, it's completely irrelevant how you write it; the compiler will do the right thing.)

Comment: @JamesKanze I partially agree and have edited the answer. However you contradict yourself - either the order is irrelevant or it depends on a compiler, but not both. I presume in the simplest case for a reference compiler without any optimization the processing order would be just linear.

Comment: @icepack Even without optimization, every compiler I've worked on starts by sorting the elements in a switch, in order to find the max and the min, and to decide whether the cases are dense or not.  So the order in a switch will have no effect what so ever.  For the `if`/`else` version, it might if you don't optimize.  But if performance is important, why wouldn't you optimize.  And with profiler output, the compiler will choose whatever is best for the actual observed frequencies.

Comment: @JamesKanze There are many cases where sorting will only worsen the performance so I wouldn't be so categorical

Comment: @icepack You need to sort in order to determine whether the cases are dense or not.  You need the cases sorted if you're going to use a jump table.  And you need the cases sorted if you're going to do a binary search.  In every compiler I've ever worked on, the first thing you do is sort the cases.

Answer (score 3):

Although you've accepted what is probably the best answer, I wanted to provide an alternative.

Note that the standard caveat applies - optimisation isn't optimisation unless you've profiled your code.

However if you are encountering poor performance relating to branches, you can reduce or eliminate them. That your code has one or more inequality comparisons is not an obstacle - you can reduce your cases down to a set of direct equalities, and if necessary use that to index a table, rather than branch at all.

```
void doSomething(int len)
{
    static const char* str[] =
    {   "%2d > 3\n",
        "%2d < 2\n",
        "%2d = 2\n",
        "%2d = 3\n"
    };

    int m1 = (len-2)>>31;
    int m2 = (len-4)>>31;

    int r = (len & m2 & ~m1) + !!m1;

    printf(str[r],len); 
}
```

Note that this codes makes several assumptions which may not hold in practice, but as we're making the wild assumption that this even needs optimising in the first place...

Also, note that better optimisations may be possible with more knowledge about the actual range and type of the input parameter, and indeed what the actual actions taken need to be.

Comment: Interesting, I see what you meant now. I wasn't thinking much beyond the switch syntax. How unbecoming of a programmer!

Comment: hi Jason. Thnaks a lot for your answer. And its interesting though. It encourages learners like me to visit SO often..

Comment: It's interesting that you can avoid any branching, but at what cost.  Given the amount of additional operations, _and_ the fact that one condition is far more frequent than the others, a good compiler will arrange that one to do no branching (assuming that a correctly predicted branch really is expensive), so all the above really achieves is obfuscation.

Comment: @JamesKanze As I said at the top, it isn't optimisation unless you've profiled. That said, I've certainly worked with compilers for which this would be a win. But assuming either case without profiling is folly.

Answer (score 2):

You can't move comparisons into a *switch* statement... it uses single checks for its selections.. i.e.,

```cpp
switch (len) {

    case 1:
        // Do case 1 stuff here
    break;

    case 2:
        // Do case 2 stuff here
    break;

    case 3:
        // Do case 3 stuff here
    break;
}
```

*Use breaks to prevent the case statements from running into each other*. Read more [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/control/).

Your code is as 'optimized' as it will get in its current state...

Answer (score 1):

If you are worried about speed, the truth is that your `if...else` or `switch...case` statements won't have a real impact of your application speed unless you have hundreds of them. The places where you lose speed is in your iterations or loops. To answer your question specifically, you cannot convert your `if...else` statement to a `switch...case` statement with the `default` appearing first; but with that said, if you did convert to a `switch...case` then you will that they run at the same speed (difference is too minute to be picked up by conventional benchmarking tools).

Comment: if `if else` or `switch case` in a loop, it will have a very real impact

Comment: I think it would depend on the size of the loop. But in this case, there is only four conditions to check; the difference would have many decimal places and is not really an area that needs to have the developer's attention.

Answer (score 1):

The only way you're going to know is to benchmark it with your
compiler.  If performance is an issue, you should use the option
to provide the compiler with profiler output, and let it decide;
it will generally find the best solution.  (Note that even on
a specific architecture, like Intel, the best solution in terms
of machine instructions may vary from one processor to the
next.)

In your case, the switch would probably look like:

```
switch ( len ) {
case 2:
    //  ...
    break;

case 3:
    //  ...
    break;

default:
    if ( len > 3 ) {
        // ...
    } else {
        // ...
    }
}
```

With only two effective cases, the compiler doesn't have much to
work with.  A typical implementation (without extreme
optimization) would do bounds checking, then a table lookup for
the two explicit cases.  Any decent compiler will then pick up
that the comparison in your `default` case corresponds to one of
the bounds checks it has already done, and not duplicate it.
But with only two cases, the jump table will probably not make
a significant difference compared to the two comparisons,
especially as you'll be out of bounds in the most frequent case.

Until you have actual profiler information that this is
a bottleneck in your code, I wouldn't worry about it.  Once you
have that information, you can profile different variants to see
which is faster, but I suspect that if you use maximum
optimization and feed profiling information back into the
compiler, there will be no difference.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a range in a case:

```
switch (len) {
  case 3 ... INT_MAX:
    // ...
    break;
  case 2:
    // ...
    break;
  default:
    // ...
    break;
 }
```

But that is an extension provided by GCC...

Comment: It says that this is not standard in here: is that still the case? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5924681/are-elipses-in-case-statements-standard-c-c

Comment: it's a nice construct :) I just hadn't ever seen it and was curious

Comment: @Caribou well as your link indicates, compiling with the -pedantic option does warn about the "non-standard-ness" (gcc 4.7.2); too bad it's not in the standard though

Comment: I agree actually - I wonder if the compiler can do any kind of optimization using this? or whether it becomes the same as the "if..else" code. One for my coffee break maybe :)