# Using sets in "switch" statement

Tags: c++, set, switch-statement

Am I able to add sets instead of numbers to "switch" statement? Like:

```
switch(number)
{
 case 1<50: //if number is between 1 and 50
 {
 blah;
 break;
 }
 case 50<100: //if number is between 50 and 100
 {
 blah;
 break;
 }
```

and so on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(Edit following comments below, acknowledgement given to user syam)

No. In C++ you can only switch on things that reduce to an integer. You'll need to build a function that computes integral results for 1 < 50 and 50 < 100 etc. and use switch(thatFunction(...)).

Or, if you don't need the follow-though idiom that a switch gives you (by the looks of your example, you don't), just use `if`, `else if`, `else`.

Extract from below comments:
*6.4.2-2 [stmt.switch] The condition shall be of integral type, enumeration type, or of a class type for which a single non-explicit conversion function to integral or enumeration type exists [...] the constant-expression shall be a converted constant expression (5.19) of the promoted type of the switch condition*

Comment: _You'll need to build a function that computes int results for 1 < 50 and 50 < 100 etc. and use switch(thatFunction(...))._ can you explain it? It sounds useful. Also, I don't want to use `if` and `else` because I'd like to use it to watch some regions on the screen and it means the use of a lot of coordinates.

Comment: @Bathsheba You can only switch on *integers* not just on `int`. `int64_t` and `char` are perfectly acceptable types.

Comment: What is the exhaustive list of things you want to switch on? You have 1 < 50 and 50 < 100, but they are pretty meaningless as they are just integer literals.

Comment: Hey syam: are you sure about that? I'm convinced (insofar that I grew up thinking) that in C any number larger than an int will introduce a periodicity in a switch. Is that not true in C++ too?

Comment: @Bathsheba: *6.4.2-2 [stmt.switch] The condition shall be of integral type, enumeration type, or of a class type for which a single non-explicit conversion function to integral or enumeration type exists [...] the constant-expression shall be a converted constant expression (5.19) of the promoted type of the switch condition.* Or just try to switch on `4294967299LL` (2^32 + 3) and have a case with `3` -- assuming of course your `int` is 32 bits and `long long` is 64 bits. ;)

Comment: Syam: If you put this as an answer I've give you +10.

Comment: @Bathsheba: nah, just edit your answer to read *integer* instead of `int` and I'll be satisfied. ;)

Answer (score 2):

`1 < 50` is a boolean expression that gets a *compile-time* value of `true`, and thus becomes `1` in an integer context. So you end up with two identical `case`s in your `switch`. Compile with high warning level - your compiler will surely complain.

Comment: I know that `1 < 50` is not a proper way for it, I just illustrated the code.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly not. You can use fall-through for a small set of discrete values:

```
case 1:
case 2:
    blah;
    break;
```

but for large ranges the only sensible option is `if...else`.

Answer (score 1):

For me, this works on my g++ (GCC) 4.7.2 20121109

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    switch(6) {
        case 1 ... 5:
            cout << "Between 1 and 5" << endl;
            break;
        case 6 ... 10:
            cout << "Between 6 and 10" << endl;
            break;
    }
}
```

Thanks for stating in the comments that it's [GCC's extenstion](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.2/gcc/Case-Ranges.html)

Comment: That's an extension, though.

Comment: you're right, it's important to mention, I was just thinking it would be nice to have it here

Comment: GCC 4.7.2 gives me a `warning: range expressions in switch statements are non-standard` (`-std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic`).

Comment: @syam - yes that's the warning (-pedantic) notifying you that it doesn't have to work apart of gcc, that's why I stated version of my compiler in the post

Answer (score 0):

Conditionals are not permitted as case statements, so your option is to use if / else statements.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that in C++. `case` switches must be a constant that can be converted to an `int`.

Answer (score 0):

This is nicely discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9432226/how-do-i-select-a-range-of-values-in-a-switch-statement).

A switch statement is useful when you have to use a single variable across many possible conditions. A switch statement works faster than an `if-else` block by using a [jump table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14067547/how-switch-case-statement-implemented-or-works-internally). It requires constant integers when it makes the table. The reason expressions that dont evaluate to a fixed value are not allowed is to save from ambiguity.

```
case 1+a;

break;

case 5;

break;
```

Now what if `a` is `4`. That will cause issues. If it doesnt use the jump table it wont be much useful than an `if-else` block