# Switch-Case Statement and Range of Numbers

Tags: objective-c

Is there a way to use switch statement with ranges in Objective C (in XCode), hypothetically something like this:

```
- (NSString *)evaluate:(NSInteger)sampleSize
{
       NSString returnStr;
       switch (sampleSize)
           {
               case sampleSize < 10: 
               returnStr = @"too small!";
               break;

               case sampleSize >11 && sampleSize <50:
               returnStr = @"appropriate";
               break;

               case sampleSize >50:
               returnStr = @"too big!";
               break;
           }
       return returnStr;
}
```

Answer (score 43):

There is a GCC extension (which I assume is supported in Clang) that might be suitable for you. It allows you to use ranges in case statements. The full documentation is at http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.2.4/gcc/Case-Ranges.html#Case-Ranges - an example case statement from that page is

```
case 1 ... 5:
```

which would match (unsurprisingly) 1, 2, 3, 4, or 5.

Comment: I just learned about this syntax when I was reading though the code here: https://github.com/atebits/OAuthCore/blob/master/OAuth%2BAdditions.m -- wish I knew about it a long time ago.

Comment: The spaces around the ellipse are required lest the parser try to interpret the numbers as a double.

Comment: Note this does not work for variables, it requires constant integer boundaries for range.

Answer (score 4):

No, switch statements are for constant values in most languages... The closest you can get is to flow the cases into one another like this:

```
switch(sampleSize)
{
    case 0:
    case 1:
    case 2:
        returnStr = @"too small!";
        break;
}
```

Alternatively, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4680502/simulater-generated-switch-statement-range-in-c) Question may help...

EDIT: I just thought of another way: you could "#define" that large list of cases in a .h file like this:

```
#define TOO_LOW     case 0: \
                    case 1: \
                    case 2: \
                    case 3:
```

and then use it in a switch like so:

```
switch(sampleSize)
{
    TOO_LOW
        returnStr = @"too small!";
        break;
}
```

Of course, thats not the cleanest solution.  What's wrong with 3 "if/else's"?

Comment: well, that works only if there are a limited number of options. If I want to go from 1 through 50 like that, it doesn't really make sense to use switch-case. I thought maybe there are some other ways to go around switch-case with ranges.

Comment: Yeah I think you're out of luck in this case.

Answer (score 4):

```
- (NSString *)evaluate:(NSInteger)sampleSize
{
       NSString returnStr;
       switch (sampleSize)
           {

    //    for sampleSize between 0 and 10

               case 0 ... 10: 
               returnStr = @"too small!";
               break;

    //    for sampleSize between 11 and 50

               case 11 ... 50:
               returnStr = @"appropriate";
               break;

    //    for sampleSize above 50

               case 50 :
               case default:
               returnStr = @"too big!";
               break;
           }
       return returnStr;
}
```

> Please Note: This is a solution i worked out but it will not count if sampleSize has h value less than 0.

Answer (score -7):

Simply pass true in your switch statement like below code

```
- (NSString *)evaluate:(NSInteger)sampleSize {
   NSString returnStr;
   switch (true)
       {
           case sampleSize < 10: 
           returnStr = @"too small!";
           break;

           case sampleSize >11 && sampleSize <50:
           returnStr = @"appropriate";
           break;

           case sampleSize >50:
           returnStr = @"too big!";
           break;
       }
   return returnStr;
```

}

This will solve your problem

Comment: I'll tell you what I wish this worked. It doesn't though: I just tested it. I don't believe in downvoting but dude check your answers before posting. "Expression is not an integer constant expression"