# Check if number matches from 1 number to another in switch statement

Tags: ios, objective-c, switch-statement

I have a `switch` statement comparing an `integer`. What I'm trying to do, is to check if the `integer` matches 1 number all the way, up until the next.

For Example: If I want to compare a `integer` called `myInteger`, and I want to see, if the numbers 2, 3, 4, 5, or 6 matches `myInteger, then do the following.

Here is a coded example:

```
switch (myInteger) {
    case 0:
        ...
    case 1:
        ...
    case 2 to 7:    // This is what I'm trying to achieve
        ...
}
```

So, how can I make the `switch` statement, iterate over a range of numbers?

Comment: And what is your question? Please try to phrase it so that there is a question mark at the end and start it with "How do I..." if possible.

Comment: Just update the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can actually do this with objective C using the ... operator.

As per your example this would find between 0 and 7 and between 8 and 14. Anything bigger is default action.

```
switch (myInteger) {
    case 0 ... 7:
      break;
    case 8 ... 14:
      break;
    default:
      break;
}
```

Try it for yourself and you'll see it works. Its a hangover from gcc support:

[Switch-Case Statement and Range of Numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8176420/switch-case-statement-and-range-of-numbers)

Answer (score -1):

C-based languages like Objective-C don't support that sort of syntax. Just use an if statement:

```
if (myInteger >= 2 && myInteger <= 7)) {
    // do stuff
}
```

In a switch statement, each case value must be a discrete constant.